# Trick to enabling FTP upload from an app in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, ftp

I have an older Win32 app that uses FTP to upload some data to a server from time to time. This app works great in Windows XP and has been working fine in Windows 7 and Vista. For some reason, when running under Windows 8 it has trouble uploading its data. It appears to connect and upload the data OK but it has times out when disconnecting. The data does not appear on the server. I have limited visibility into the app while it's running so sorry for the vague nature of the description.

My question is: Is there some security setting in Windows 8 that would keep this app from using FTP? When I check the settings it looks to me like I have it set up to prompt me about any permissions problems it might have, and I'm not seeing any prompts.

I've tried running this app in XP/SP3 compatibility mode with no luck.

At this point I'm just looking for some clues as to where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Do check your firewall

and also you can check your ftp service under verbose mode to diagnose any connection issues there .

```
ftp -v  yourftpserveraddress
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it has an exception to Windows Firewall to access the network you are moving the files over. If not, add one for it and try the upload again. In your new Windows 8 setup, it is possible that the rule was not asked for by Windows but defaulted to "deny" for some reason, especially if it does not have any windows, but only runs in the background.